# How To View the Project > References Tab and All DLL Paths in non-VB projects?

Tags: visual-studio

When you create a VB project in Visual Studio there is a 'References' tab in the Project Properties window. It looks like this:

[image]

It's rather a helpful window as it shows the paths to all the referenced DLLs in one place and lets you add and remove references easily.

However this same tab does not appear for projects in other languages making it very difficult to check the path for each referenced DLL.

Can this tab be made viewable or available for other projects? If not, what is the simplest way to view all the referenced DLL paths at once?

Comment: and please don't post comments that start language wars

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the reference tab for the other languages does not exist.

But you can try to edit the xml project, with these steps:

- Show the context menu on your project in the window solution explorer
- Select: Unload project
- Right click and select Edit
- Edit the ProjectReference element in xml file
- Save and close xml
- Reload Project (right click in solution explorer)

I know this is not what you wanted, but it could be a quick alternative to display the path of your references.